# Megento 1.9.3.1 please tell me how to fix this

Tags: php, file-upload, magento1.9.3.1

Friends this is very major issue,in magento 1.9.3.1 this below issue is frustrating and no solutions I found since last one week.

kindly help me to revert back the cause and solution so that i may get back the **all PRODUCTS IMAGES AND BROWSE FILES AND UPLOAD FILES** buttons for **MAGENTO 1.9.3.1**

Comment: did you checked in other browsers regarding `browse` buttons, you may need `adobe flash player` , also is images not displaying in site & in backend ?

Comment: if it is your browser is safari you have to install flash player

Answer (score 2):

This is confirmed issue of browser. Install flash player and you can also check in Google Chrome. Opera is another option.

This is very old issue not a new one so no need to worry. Please check in different browser and if its not sorted then please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the **flash player** issue.If it is your browser is **safari** you have to **install flash player**.I faced the same issue in safari browser and fixed it after installing the flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's Flash Player issue in browser. please check in other browser to displayed button and image upload. use firefox and update your chrome browers.